# how to remove inertia unity3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a ball that jumps up a ladder, but when the jump ends, the ball still moves a short distance. It used to travel long distances and I just set freezeRotation = true, but the inertia still remained.
I would be glad to any advice. Here is my code

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;

public class ballcontroller : MonoBehaviour
{
    //public int speed = 3;
    
    public int jumpForce;
    public bool IsGround;

    private Rigidbody rb;

    private void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        //float Vm = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
        //float Hm = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        
        //Vector3 V3M = new Vector3(Hm, 0, Vm);
        
        //rb.AddForce(V3M * speed);

        Jump();
    }

    public void Jump()
    {
        Ray ray = new Ray(gameObject.transform.position, Vector3.down);
        RaycastHit rh;
        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out rh, 0.5f))
        {
            IsGround = true;
        }
        else
        {
            IsGround = false;
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && IsGround)
        {
            rb.AddForce(Vector3.one * jumpForce);
            rb.freezeRotation = true;
            
        }
        
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can directly manipulate the velocity of your rigidbody using `Rigidbody.velocity` and `Rigidbory.angularVelocity`.
You could set it to `Vector3.zero` (or decrease it slowly to avoid hard freezing) after you hit the ground.